# All $n$ such that $n+2$ is a cube and $n-2$ is a square.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> I'm trying to find all integers $n$ such that $n+2$ is a cube and $n-2$ is a square.

I already know that only 6 and 123 are solutions but not know how to show it. I tried to use the proof of 26 being the only one such that $n+1$ is a cube and $n-1$ is a square but I'm having troubles doing it as in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ I don't know how to conclude that if $y^3=x^2+4=(x+2i)(x-2i)$ then both $x+2i$ and $x-2i$ are cubes (It is at least true?).

Thank you very much.

Comment: As part of the generalization of the [Catalan Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), now Mihăilescu's theorem, it is believed that $4,32,121$ are the only perfect powers $n$ such that $n+4$ is also a perfect power.  I don't know if this statement has been proven or not, though some of the references cited in the wiki article may have more details.

Comment: It would be nice to have a reference to/copy of the proof that you're trying to emulate.

Comment: The approach is correct, but I do not have much experience with calculations with gaussian integers, so I do not know exactly how we can show that both factors have to be cubes. I only remember that you need the norm and the $\gcd$ somehow ...

Comment: @MichaelBurr Here is a link with a sketch of the proof I referred to. https://www.quora.com/Is-Fermats-conjecture-that-26-is-the-only-number-sandwiched-by-the-square-and-the-cube-of-integers-25-5-2-%E2%89%A4-26%E2%89%A4-27-3-3-proved

Comment: if the two statements are true so is n^2-4 is a fifth power. the lowest fifth power is closest to the square of 6.  so that proves a minimum.

Comment: It is still an open problem to prove that the  number of perfect powers $n$ for which $n+4$ is also a perfect power is even finite. The case of squares and cubes is of course much easier to handle.

Comment: [Here's a paper by Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) showing different examples of these equations; yours is on page 6.

Comment: This is the Mordell curve $y^2=x^3-4.$ I'm fairly sure this is known, and that  $x=2$ and $x=5$ are the only integer points. For data on Mordell curves see [e.g.](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~bmatschke/data/allSolutions_r_1_maxA_10_n_100000.txt).